# How is the Get<T> method used with DynamicParameters?

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to run a test to see if I loaded a `DynamicParameters` object correctly. However, I cannot figure out what the Type is that I should use. I get exceptions when I try to use C#/.NET types (int, string, etc.). I tried to use SqlDbType, but that didn't work. I looked at source and I see that the value is stored as a `IDbDataParameter` and then cast to the type. Obviously, the types I'm trying don't cast.  The data I'm testing with are `int`. How can I get the values?

```
var dbParams = new DynamicParameters();
dbParams.Add( "Field1", 1 );
var value = dbParams.Get<int>( "Field1" ); // throws an exception
```

Comment: The *parameter objects* are typed as that interface. Not the values. The values are via `.Value`. What you describe should work. Can you be more specific about the scenario? What is the server? What is the parameter?

Comment: I curious why the question got downvoted. Is asking a question about how a method works wrong somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The code only *expected* `Get<T>` to be used **after** the SQL had been invoked, in order to obtain the updated value of `ref`, `out` and `return` parameters. Consequently it attempted to de-reference something that *didn't exist yet*. This will be fixed in the next release ([it is fixed in the trunk now](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/24e55162f47780f509ee373c081234431bc5d576)).